# Skype Addon in C#

Tags: c#, skype, add-on

I would like to try and build a Skype Addon in C#. Is there an API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.skype.com/Download

youll need a c# wrapper to use their sdks

Comment: Link no longer exists. Might want to use http://developer.skype.com/. Not sure if you have to sign up to the BETA though?

Answer (score 2):

I am talking about July 2010.

1. Skype has a very bad documentation out there. Putting more or less business tricks rather then developers freedom
2. Personally i dont prefer this, but its ok to use for C#: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SEHE
3. Working in Linux/Unix is nightmare to make things for Skype.

God bless skype for linux.

Comment: I agree, I gave up on trying to do anything useful with their API, it sucks balls and reminds me of sendKeys, rather than a serious API.

Comment: @JL, did you find anything for this then?

Answer (score 1):

You can import the Skype API DLL (Skype4COM) to your project as a reference, than you can access the stuff inside.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> To add a reference in Visual C# or Visual J#
>
> ```
> In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project node and click Add Reference.
> In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
> Select the components you want to reference, then click OK.
> ```