# use Skype4COM.dll COM API in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, dll, skype4com

I will like to use the skype dll classes in visual studio. The link where I have downloaded skype4com.dll is in [here](https://developer.skype.com/accessories/skype4com). When I try to add a reference to that dll I get:

[image]

I tried following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260011/637142) but the link is broken.

### edit

I have also tried following [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SEHE.aspx):

but when I open the project visual studio cannot load:

[image]

Comment: Related tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SEHE.aspx

Comment: Try looking at this [MSDN Skype Event Handler Example](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SEHE/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1871), they have example code and links to download the Skype4COM.dll.

Comment: I have tried that example but cannot use the library... Take a look at my edit. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has the COM DLL been registered? How are you setting up your reference? In order to use your COM reference you need to select it from the COM tab in the Add Reference dialog rather than selecting the DLL file from the Browse tab.

Comment: Exactly I needed to register the dll. I found the answer at: http://donchevp.blogspot.com/2008/08/skype4com-lib-how-to-register-skype.html