# Getting error on using Skype4ComLib

Tags: c#, .net, skype4com

Hi I am using Skype4ComLib to retrieve Skype contacts but I am getting error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {830690FC-BF2F-47A6-AC2D-330BCB402664} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Skype is installed on my machine.

any idea?

Answer (score 5):

I recently experienced the exact same error message, and it was simply as a result of my .NET project being compiled for "Any CPU" by default.

The SKYPE4COM library is a 32bit only binary, and as such you should make sure that the project you intend to use it with is specifically compiled for "x86" architecture.

As soon as I did this, the error message just went away.

Simply right-click on your project and select "properties". Then under the "Build" tab, choose "x86" where it says "platform target". This process may vary with your version of Visual Studio, but is correct as of version 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Have you registered the DLL?  Take a look at this [Blog](http://donchevp.blogspot.com/2008/08/skype4com-lib-how-to-register-skype.html)

From above blog:

> In the command prompt type : regsvr32 Skype4COM.dll or "regsvr32
>   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype\Skype4COM.dll"

---

Also try taking a look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8875627/479512)

Comment: I tried out this, but it throws error "The specified module couldn't be found" though, Skype4ComLib exist at the specified path

Comment: @BreakHead Per chance are you using 64 bit Windows? Try looking at this [Daniweb thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/317068)