# Skype4COM.dll not able to register

Tags: c#, automation, skype, skype4com

I am working on automating Skype applcation using C# Skype4COMlib.dll.

When I try to register the dll, I am getting the below error as in the snapshot. If anyone have an idea on how to register the Skype dll please share your ideas here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you trying register .net-dll library. I think so because the original name of the file is Skype4COM.dll.
You need register com-library and then `Add Reference...` to your project from `COM-tab`->`Type Libraries`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875627/use-skype4com-dll-com-api-in-visual-studio)