# Using Skype API to make call

Tags: c#, api, skype

I am trying to making call programmatically through Skype. Skype is installed in my PC but when I am trying to make call through Skype API & C# then every time I am getting a exception called `Connection refuse` and I am not being able to fix it. So, looking for proper guide to solve the issue.

Here is code snippet by which I am trying to make call programmatically.

```
Skype skype;
skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
string SkypeID = "+222222222";
Call call = skype.PlaceCall(SkypeID);
do
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
} while (call.Status != TCallStatus.clsInProgress);
```

Please guide me what is missing in my code. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you supply your credentials to make the connection?

Comment: [This](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=73172) or [this one](http://blogs.skype.com/developer/2006/12/c_example_project_for_skype4co.html) can help

Comment: how to supply my credential because apps may not run in my pc rather it may run in another pc where some one logged in his skype. i want to use his skype to make call.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259923/implementation-of-skype-api?rq=1

Comment: check this url 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SEHE/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Home&version=7
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31009/Skype-COM-Event-Handler-Example-for-ALL-Skype-API

http://donchevp.blogspot.in/2008/08/skype4com-lib-how-to-register-skype.html
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SEHE/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1871
https://code.google.com/p/sacj/downloads/detail?name=MultipleS4CExample.zip&can=2&q
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/skype4com/hot

Comment: Most of the links above are broken or not updated. Any chance you can publish an updated tutorial to make a Skype call in c++?

Comment: sorry i have no idea about c++. skype has a particular dll file Skype4COM Lib which you may try to interact with skype. follow this url http://donchevp.blogspot.in/2008/08/skype4com-lib-how-to-register-skype.html