# C# Skype Plugin

Tags: c#, skype

There seems to be VERY little documentation on how to do this online so thought I would ask here...

Basically I want to make a very simple Skype plugin that will only be used within chat windows, and would either be triggered by a button press (if you can add buttons in easily) or/and entering a command into skype i.e "/CallMySkypePlugin"

Ideally I just want to know how to hook into skype this way, ive got Skype4COM but it doesn't say how your plugin gets called or where the entry point for skype is...

I was ideally expecting to make a new class library, then have a class that implements a Skype interface or something (for them to have an entry point), then within there latch onto a chat window "MessageSent" event or something, then call my method... i.e

```
public class MySkypePlugin : SkypeEntryPointInterface
{
    // The main skype functionality class
    private void Skype skype = new Skype();

    // Something like this as the entry point
    public void SkypeEntryPoint()
    { 
        skype.MessageSent += ChatWindow_MessageSent;
    }

    // Do my stuff here
    private void ChatWindow_MessageSent(SkypeEvent e) { ... }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Just to add some clarity, I do *not* want to write an Application that uses skype, I want to write a plugin that skype uses...

Comment: It appears what im after is Skype Extras, which were discontinued... why they have stopped people making plugins in favour of standalone applications is beyond me... I will give evandrix the answer even though it didnt answer the question, but at least you responded :)

Comment: For anyone still interested in this, I found a single post somewhere in the Skype support forums a few months ago which details that they are making a specific C# wrapper for Skype. I hope that replaces the awful Skype4Com which is so difficult to develop for in c# that it is almost not worth while.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skype Addon in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149615/skype-addon-in-c-sharp)

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: I just wrote my own c# app in the end and hooked into skype, the results can be found here: https://github.com/grofit/SkypeRoller problem for me was that it seemed very sketchy, in certain versions of skype it wouldnt work and the users had to do a lot of leg work in some cases to get it working so I stopped working on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your question (or at least a similar one) has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259923/implementation-of-skype-api) before.

Please do check it out and see if it helps.

If not, a quick google search turns up the following results that you might like to check out, personally, I think examples are the way to go in getting these things to work, just by experimenting and playing around:-

1. [Skype4COM C#.Net Example](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=73172)
2. [Example from Skype Developer Blog](http://blogs.skype.com/developer/2006/12/c_example_project_for_skype4co.html)
3. [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/skypecontrolapicsharp.aspx)
4. [Skype API Documentation](http://skypejournal.com/downloads/2005/001/SJ200500101en_WorkingWithTheSkypeAPI.pdf)

...a more complete list is available here with this [search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=C%23+skype+api), for your reference.

Comment: Hi,Ive read alot of these so far, and gained some decent information from them. The thing I dont get is that alot of these examples are how to use skype in another application, i.e you load up your app then start sending and receiving data from skype. However I want skype to kick off my app automatically as a plugin (if possible) and then just start doing stuff in the background there... All the examples out there have the user kicking off your skype app, whereas I want skype to kick it off automatically...

Comment: 4th link is dead. I've found another [doc](http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference)

Comment: @DenisTheMenace, your link is also dead)